# Bott connection

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles

Can anyone help me showing the following: Let $E$ be a smooth vector bundle over $M$ and $F\subseteq TM$ a smooth distribution. A $F$-connection is a $\mathbb R$-bilinear aplication $$\nabla:\Gamma(F)\times \Gamma(E)\rightarrow \Gamma(E),$$
where $\Gamma(E)$ is the set of all smooth sections of $E$, $(X, e)\mapsto \nabla_Xe$, such that
for every $f\in C^\infty(M)$, $X\in \Gamma(F)$ and $e\in \Gamma(E)$:

**(i)** $\nabla_{fX}e=f\nabla_Xe$.

**(ii)** $\nabla_X(fe)=f\nabla_Xe+X(f)e$.

If $F=\{F_p; p\in M\}\subseteq TM$ is an involutive distribution show that the map:

$$\nabla:\Gamma(F)\times \Gamma(\nu(F))\rightarrow \nabla(\nu(F)),\ (X, \overline{Y})\mapsto \overline{[X, Y]},$$

is a $F$-conection in the normal bundle $\displaystyle\nu(F)=\bigcup_{p\in M}\nu(F_p)$ where $\nu(F_p)=T_pM/F_p$. 
The map $\nabla$ is called Bott connection.

**Obs:** $[X, Y]$ is the Lie Bracket.

Comment: Do you have an answer, Dion?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that $M$ has a riemman metric, you can build a projection $p:TM\to\nu$ this is a morphism betwenn vector bundles. Than define $\nabla_{X}Y=p([X,Y])$, you can look that $p$ is linear over each fiber, more properties of Lie Bracket you show what you want.
Have you studed foliations?

Comment: Yeah, I know something about foliations.. Hey, I'm also brasilian, from UFPR =)

Comment: Really? It's nice, i'm from Unicamp. I'm studing something about foliations... what're things you are studing now?

Comment: Yeah.. cool =) Indeed I study pseudo-differential operators however I enjoy a lot studying the geometry of manifolds and vector bundles and also Lie groups.. Are you a master or Ph.D. student? Who's your advisor there? There are some people working with foliations over here too..

Comment: I'm master degree student and you? My advisor is Diego S. Ledesma. I'm studing the elliptc operator that describes the deformation of a foliation. If you need talk anything else you could send me an e-mail for ra134327@ime.unicamp.br

Comment: Great =) I'm in the second semester of the Ph.D. program..That sounds an interesting problem... Ok, thanks, my email is dion.rss@gmail.com.. we talk.. Good luck with your dissertation =)